# locate the path of other drive's folder in server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, path

How to locate the path of other drive's folder in server?

For ex: 
The application is there in 'C:\SomeFolder\', now I want to export a file to the drive 'D:\AnotherFolder\' on the server. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to have permissions to access the folder. The user that needs to be able to access the folder is the same user as is running IIS. Usualy it is a built in account `IIS_*` that is running the instance.

As long as this user has access to the folder, you can just use File Read / Write as you normally  do.

Read this article about [C# File Handling](http://dotnetperls.com/file-handling).

**Example - Search for files on another drive**

`var files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\", "*.txt");`

This will give you an array of files with the extension `.txt` found on `D:\`.

Also read this: [How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

Comment: I mean to ask, how can I locate the file-path which is not in the drive where the application resides?

Comment: @Knvn, Exactly the same way you would do when it is on the same drive as your application. If you were to give me an example of what you really want to do. I might be able to help you out more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I want to save a file on the specific path.

Comment: Oh! thank you so much. Actually I've put a wrong path, hence it was giving me the 'path not found error'. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get a list of all drives known on a system you can use [Environment.GetLogicalDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getlogicaldrives.aspx).